# My default prop to following flags set in default.prop:

Tags: android

How to change
My default prop to following flags set in default.prop:
I have a android device.

```
ro.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
ro.adb.secure=0
```

Comment: Seems solution is there http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Rooting. To edit this file you need root access and to follow that tutorial you need stock firmware.
And backup everything you need and can. While I was following that tutorial my device decided to reflash everything to factory defaults and I've lost the everything I had on my device. So my solution might be not only too late, but not suitable for you at all :(.

Answer (score 1):

default.prop is located in initrd aka ramdisk of the boot.img using abootimg you can extract the ramdisk and kernel from boot.img

Here is info on initrd https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt

Here is info on abootimg http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/abootimg.1.html